# How to speed up computation over multiple arrays in python

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Suppose we have `a`, `b`, `c`, three arrays of same dimension, and that we need to do computations based on each column of `a`, `b`, `c`.

An example would be like:

```
import numpy as np 

col = 10
row = 1000000
a = np.random.normal(size=(row, col))
b = np.random.normal(size=(row, col))
c = np.random.normal(size=(row, col))

def my_func(a, b, c):
    if a[0] + b[0] + b[-1] > c[0]:
        return a * b * c
    else:
        return a * (b[1] + b[-1]) + c[-1]

for i in range(num):
    my_func(a[:, i], b[:, i], c[:, i])
```

The first thought is use numpy, however since the computation is not homogeneous and over several arrays, `numpy.apply_along_axes` does not work.
In this case, is there any suggestion to speed up the computation above in python instead of using c?

Comment: What is `num`? Is it `col`?

Comment: Are you worrying about 10 iterations? It is this a toy example? In the latter case, I'd swap the dimensions to make the exigency more apparent.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is a speed-tool.  It's just a convenience when working with 3d (or greater) dimensions, and your `fn` only operates on 1d.

Answer (score 2):

When using `numpy` you need to consider vectorizing the computation in `my_func` to speed up your code. In this case you could try something like this:

```
cond = np.broadcast_to(a[0] + b[0] + b[-1] > c[0], a.shape)
result = np.where(cond, a * b * c, a * (b[1] + b[-1]) + c[-1])
```

Here, computations like `a[0] + b[0]` is performed on two arrays rather than element by element.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/). It is very simple, you just add a Python Decorator `@jit` to the function, there might be compatibility issues but usually if it is just simple Python or Numpy code it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you ask how to speed up the computation in python "instead of using c".
If it's just C, but you're open to other environments generally, this may be of use to you.

> "If you want your code to run faster, you should probably just use PyPy.”
>
> — Guido van Rossum (creator of Python)

https://www.pypy.org/index.html
You will have to install their interpreter but you won't be rewriting anything. PyPy supports numpy as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up the loop with numpy, even though ten iterations of a python `for` loop are usually not prohibitively expensive under normal circumstances.

A first order optimization would be to compute both branches in `my_func`, and then use something like [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to do the selection for you. This is somewhat wasteful of space, which means that it also wastes time on unnecessary allocations, not to mention computing both results for all elements.

A better way would be to make a mask:

```
def my_func_2D(a, b, c):
    mask = (a[0, :] + b[0, :] + b[-1, :] > c[0, :])
    result = np.empty_like(a)
    result[:, mask] = a[:, mask] * b[:, mask] * c[:, mask]
    result[:, ~mask] = a[:, ~mask] * (b[1, ~mask] + b[-1, ~mask]) + c[-1, ~mask]    
    return result
```

This only performs the necessary computations, but it stashes the intermediate calculations in potentially unnecessary buffers.

A better way to do this might be to use [masked arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html). They will let you perform the computations you want in-place. Using [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html#numpy.broadcast_to), you can even avoid making a full-sized mask:

```
def my_func_2D(a, b, c):
    mask = (a[0, :] + b[0, :] + b[-1, :] > c[0, :])
    result = ma.masked_array(a.copy(), mask=np.broadcast_to(mask, a.shape))
    bm = ma.masked_array(b, np.broadcast_to(mask, b.shape))
    cm = ma.masked_array(c, np.broadcast_to(mask, c.shape))
    result *= bm[1, :] + bm[-1, :]
    result += cm[-1, :]
    np.logical_not(mask, out=mask)
    result *= b
    result *= c
    return result.data
```

The masked arrays we create (except the result) are all cheap views. The result is computed in-place, with the masked elements untouched. The only temporary buffers we create are `mask` and `bm[1, :] + bm[-1, :]`, which are along a single dimension, and therefore relatively cheap.

Comment: A couple of typos in the 1st function: `a.empty_like` and `c[c, mask]`.  In the 2nd, with np 1.17, `result` mask is read-only.

Comment: I haven't got your masked array working yet, but @GZD's answer is faster than the OP's, while your first is slower.  As you comment, 10 iterations is not a slow process in `numpy`.

Comment: @hpaulj. Thanks for the catches and the benchmarking. I'm pulling this out of my behind on mobile right now.

Comment: @hpaulj. I figured modifying the base array shouldn't be a problem regardless of whether the mask is read-only. I'll investigate when I get the chance. Perhaps there's a `mask.flags['WRITEABLE'] = True` that needs to happen somewhere.

Comment: The performance of Numpy's built-in masked arrays in the `numpy.ma` module was significantly worse than regular Numpy arrays in my past experiments when I tried to use that for similar SO problems like this.

Comment: @GZ0. You're probably right. Most of the functions in `np.ma` do basically what my first option is suggesting, instead of doing the selection in C. I think the exception *might* be the in-place arithmetic operators. Either way, this answer is turning out to be crap. I was just hoping there was a way to do the math only at the necessary locations instead of over both branches.

Comment: I explored using the `where` parameter of a `ufunc` to avoid the full calculations, but no improvement, so far.

Comment: @Mad Physicist As for the first option, every indexing like `a[:, mask]` creates a copy of the selected columns into a new array. So there is added overhead in memory allocation and data copying. Hence it would only be faster if the computation overhead in my solution outweighs the memory allocation overhead, e.g. for more complex computations.